# Retrigger failed build through a script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

I have ci job in jenkins which triggers for every change in gerrit it triggers ci build  is there any possible way to retrigger through script

Comment: Trying to retrigger failed build through script already have retrigger option in ui trying to do it with script

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about automatically restarting the build if it fails, you need to first create a `post` failure section that would run every time your build fails. You then need to use `build` pointing to the same pipeline so that a new job is scheduled. Something like this:

```
post {
  failure {
    build(job: '<your_job_name>', wait: false)
  }
}
```

If the job is parameterized, you can pass the parameters from your current job. Your current job will then fail and the a new job which basically a duplicate of your recently finished job will have started running.

On the other hand, if you are asking about ways to trigger a build without using the UI (by using some shell script somewhere for example), then consider using the [Remote Access API](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/).